# Change message on Alert dialog or a better solution

Tags: android

I displayed a `DIALOG_start_NFC` alert dialog on screen, and I want to dismiss it in method `MethodName` and show dialog `DIALOG_Process_CertificateGeneration` and change message on alert dialog `DIALOG_Process_CertificateGeneration` for each step.
But in method `MethodNam Desplaymsg()` is executed but `DIALOG_start_NFC` does not dismiss . and I can not get dialog `DIALOG_Process_CertificateGeneration`

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle args) {
    switch (id) {

        case DIALOG_start_NFC :
            // A dialog that we show when we are ready to write to a tag:
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("title")
                    .setMessage("msg ")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int arg) {
                            d.cancel();
                        }
                    })
                    .setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface d) {
                            bstartnfc = false;
                        }
                    }).create();
        case DIALOG_Process_CertificateGeneration:

            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("title")
                    .setMessage(args.getString("msg"))
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("confirm ",new
                            DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }).create();



    }
}
```

I use it for this method:

```
private void MethodName()
{
    Desplaymag("method2");
    method2();

    Desplaymag( "method3");
    method3();
}

private void DisplayMsg(String msg)
{
    Bundle arg= new Bundle();
    arg.putString("msg"," step: " + msg);
    CertificateGenerationActivity.this.showDialog(DIALOG_Process_CertificateGeneration,arg);
}
```

I want to get message `method2` before execut `Methode2` and for `Method3` too. but in this code after executed `method2` and `method3`, my message is changed